# No transaction history with Paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, payment, sandbox

I try to use Expresscheckout payment with Paypal and php.
My test works fine, i can get status "success" after "Doexpresscheckout" but in my Sandbox account, i see no transaction.
If someone has solution, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction history works with your test accounts, you test accounts are:

```
yourEmail-facilitator@yourdomain.com
yourEmail-buyer@yourdomain.com
```

You can review your accounts on: "developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts" after log into the page with your original paypal account.

These e-mails are not real accounts but they are for use in tests on [sandbox](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/mx/webapps/mpp/merchant) where you can make fake transactions in order to test you development. Then after this test, you will se your history on https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications

Hope this can help you. Regards!

Comment: Hello Ivan, thank you, i forgot how to use the sandbox but everything is ok now !